# R: How to automatically create flag variables for sequences of values?

Tags: r

Suppose, you're given the following dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame(var = c(",1,2,3,", ",2,3,5,", ",1,3,5,5,"))
```

What I am looking for is to create the variables flag_1, ..., flag_7 in a containing the information of how many times the respective values occur. For a, I would expect the following result:

```
var       flag_1 flag_2 flag_3 flag_4 flag_5
",1,2,3,"   1.     1.     1.    0.     0.
",2,3,5,"   0.     1.     1.    0.     1.
",1,3,5,5," 1.     0.     1.    0.     2.
```

I managed to get the result using a nested for-loop and an if-condition but there must be a nicer (more aesthetic and better performing) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to do `strsplit`, get the `table` and then `cbind` with original data

```
cbind(a, do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(a$var), ","), 
      function(x) table(factor(x[nzchar(x)], levels = 1:5, labels = paste0("flag_", 1:5))))))
#           var flag_1 flag_2 flag_3 flag_4 flag_5
#1   ,1,2,3,      1      1      1      0      0
#2   ,2,3,5,      0      1      1      0      1
#3 ,1,3,5,5,      1      0      1      0      2
```

---

Another option is with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_extract_all(a$var, "[0-9]") %>% 
      map(~ as.integer(.x) %>%
                as_tibble)  %>% 
      bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
      count(grp, value = factor(value, levels = min(value):max(value))) %>% 
      spread(value, n, drop = FALSE, fill = 0) %>% 
      select(-grp) %>%
      bind_cols(a, .) %>%
      rename_at(vars(matches("^[0-9]+$")), ~ paste0("flag_", .))
#         var flag_1 flag_2 flag_3 flag_4 flag_5
#1   ,1,2,3,      1      1      1      0      0
#2   ,2,3,5,      0      1      1      0      1
#3 ,1,3,5,5,      1      0      1      0      2
```

Comment: @ akrun Thanks for your quick suggestion - I like the idea. In addition, it allows me to provide a vector containing the levels, which is nice since I am planning to use it for longer and more irregular sequences.

Comment: @ akrun Thanks for the additional solution using tidyverse! How would you change the pattern used in str_extract_all/rename_at to detect all values between commas and not only values between 0 and 9. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickBalada  Suppose you have letters/words as well, then try `str_extract_all(",1,2,3,abc, n fd, 4,", "[^,]+")[[1]]#
[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "abc"   " n fd" " 4"`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't make the strings into factors. Nothing good comes from that.

```
a <- data.frame(var = c(",1,2,3,", ",2,3,5,", ",1,3,5,5,"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

To get from strings to your table is simple enough if we take it in small steps. Here, I've written (or renamed) a function per step and then gone through the steps using `lapply` one at a time. You can string it all together in a pipeline if like, but it would be roughly these steps.

First, I extract the numbers from the strings. That involves splitting on commas, getting rid of empty strings, you have those because you can begin and end a string with a comma, but otherwise, that step wouldn't be necessary. Then we need to translate the strings into numbers, count how often we see each (we can do that with the `as.numeric` and `table` functions, respectively), and then it is just a question of mapping the observed counts into a table that also includes those we haven't observed.

```
pick_indices <- function(str) unlist(strsplit(str, split = ","))
remove_empty <- function(chrs) chrs[nchar(chrs) > 0]
get_indices  <- as.numeric
to_counts    <- table
to_flag_vect <- function(counts, len) {
    vec <- rep(0, len)
    names(vec) <- 1:len
    vec[names(counts)] <- counts
    vec
}

strings <- lapply(a$var, pick_indices)
cleaned <- lapply(strings, remove_empty)
indices <- lapply(cleaned, get_indices)
counts  <- lapply(indices, to_counts)
flags   <- lapply(counts, to_flag_vect, len = 5)
```

We now have the flag-counts in a list, so to make it into the table you want, with the column names you want, we simply do this:

```
tbl <- do.call(rbind, flags)
colnames(tbl) <- paste0("flag_", 1:5)
tbl
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Split and unlist the values into a factor with appropriate levels

```
x = strsplit(a$var, ",")
xp = factor(unlist(x), levels = seq_len(5))
```

Create an index that maps the values of `xp` to the rows they came from

```
i = rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x))
```

use `xtabs()` to cross-tabulate the entries by row

```
xt = xtabs(~ i + xp)
```

and `cbind()` the matrix representation of the result to the original

```
> cbind(a, unclass(xt))
        var 1 2 3 4 5
1   ,1,2,3, 1 1 1 0 0
2   ,2,3,5, 0 1 1 0 1
3 ,1,3,5,5, 1 0 1 0 2
```